# Access LinkedIn r_fullprofile with LinkedIn Developer Partner Program?

Tags: linkedin-api

I tried to reach out to LinkedIn support for more information on how to get LinkedIn Developer Partnership to access the full LinkedIn API and gain access to a user's LinkedIn Full Profile, but they directed me to StackOverflow to use the Linkedin tag. Does anybody know who I should get in touch with to access the full LinkedIn profile API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linkedin removed r_fullprofile feature after update to api v2. See attached image with official support response.

[image]